# Add up each element in two uneven arrays in Java

Tags: java

Im Swedish so maybe I did give the wrong title.

I have two arrays of different size:
{2, 5, 10, 13}
{5, 7, 5, 22, 44, 75}

I want to add each element and put it in a third array.

So the result should be {7, 12, 15, 25, 44, 75}

I have manage to done some code.

I get an exeption of out of bounds.

I think the problem is that I can´t add a non existing element.

But how can I solve it?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] samling = {1, 2, 4, 3, 8}; 
     int[] samling2 = {1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 8, 3}; 

     int[] svar = concateArrays(samling, samling2);

     for(int i=0; i < svar.length; i++)
         System.out.println("Ny Array " + svar[i]);

}

    public static int[] concateArrays(int[] samling, int[] samling2)
     {
         int sum = samling.length + samling2.length;
         int[] total = new int[sum];

         for(int i=0; i < total.length; i++){
             //if (samling2.length != 0) // || samling.length != 0)
                 total[i] = samling[i] + samling2[i];
         }


         return total;


     }
```

Comment: what is the criteria you use to add element to the new array?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to add the first elements, then the second, the third, ..., until you reach the end of the smallest array, or do you want to add each element of one array with each element of the other array?

Comment: I want to add each element of one array to the other. So if the first element is 5 in one array and 7 in the second then is should add up to 13 in the third array.

Answer (score 8):

The length of the output array shouldn't be the sum of lengths of the input arrays, it should be the length of the longer input array. And before accessing an element of either input array, you must check the current index `i` is a valid index of that array.

```
public static int[] concateArrays(int[] samling, int[] samling2)
{
    int[] total = new int[Math.max(samling.length,samling2.length)];

    for(int i=0; i < total.length; i++) {
        total[i] = (i < samling.length ? samling[i] : 0) +
                   (i < samling2.length ? samling2[i] : 0);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one loop to loop over both arrays simultaneously.

- You first need to check which array is the longest, and make a new array:

  ```
  int[] arr = new int[longest];
  ```
- Then you need to walk over the array. In this example, I assume the latter array is always the longest.

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < samling2.length; i++) {
      int totalValue = samling[i];
      if (i < samling.length) {
          totalValue += samling2[i];
      }
      arr[i] = totalValue;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of length equal to max of the two arrays you have. Then you can add the elements from both arrays if the specific index exist in both arrays else simply copy the index from the array which contain that index.

See the following code to get a better picture

```
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] samling = {1, 2, 4, 3, 8}; 
     int[] samling2 = {1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 8, 3}; 

     int[] svar = concateArrays(samling, samling2);

    System.out.println("Ny Array :");
     for(int i=0; i < svar.length; i++)
         System.out.print(svar[i] + " ");

}

    public static int[] concateArrays(int[] samling, int[] samling2)
     {
         int len = 0;

         if (samling.length > samling2.length)
            len = samling.length;
        else
            len = samling2.length;

         int[] total = new int[len];

         for(int i=0; i < len; i++){

            if (i >= samling2.length) {

                total[i] = samling[i];
            }else if( i >= samling.length) {

                total[i] = samling2[i];
            }else{

                total[i] = samling2[i] + samling[i];
            }


         }


         return total;


     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public static int[] concateArrays(int[] samling, int[] samling2)
{
    int minLength = samling.length;
    int[] array = null;
    if (samling2.length > samling.length) {
        array = samling2;
    } else {
        minLength = samling2.length;
        array = samling;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        array[i] = samling[i] + samling2[i];
    }

    return array;
 }
```

Comment: This would overwrite the contents of  `samling`

Comment: Yes ... and ? Is that a problem ?

Comment: I think so. The function that OP posted is creating and returning a new array. It's not overwriting the arrays given as inputs.

Comment: imagine having the code in a method and calling it twice.... would you expect to get the same output each time?

Comment: I edited by putting the code within a method. I don't really understand what you says... Because each time I call this method (with differents parameters), it is not returning the same output. You can try.

Comment: `int[] samling = ...; int[] samling2 = ...; int[] result1 = concateArrays(samling, samling2); int[] result2 = concateArrays(samling, samling2); ` Are `result1` and `result2` the same? Also, see what happened to `samling` and `samling2`

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, with no need for a conditional operation in each iteration of the copying loop:

```
public static int[] concateArrays(int[] samling, int[] samling2)
{
    // max length of the two arrays
    int maxLen = Math.max(samling.length,samling2.length);

    // decide which of the inputs is shorter and which is longer
    int[] shorter = maxLen == samling.length ? samling2 : samling;
    int[] longer = maxLen == samling.length ? samling : samling2;

    int[] total = new int[maxLen];

    // add both as long as there are elements in the shorter
    for(int i=0; i < shorter.length; i++) {
        total[i] = shorter[i] + longer[i];
    }

    // copy the remainder of the longer
    for(int i=shorter.length; i < longer.length; i++) {
        total[i] = longer[i];
    }   

    return total;
}
```